# Stored procedure output variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a procedure that takes a parameter 'table' for the query, and result as the output parameter. However, it shows as undeclared variable: result

I have doubled checked that no spelling mistake but still have no idea how it happened. Would someone please provide some help or guidance

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Function`(IN table varchar(10), OUT result varchar (10))
BEGIN

    SET @q = CONCAT ('
        Select `field` from `',table,'` into result limit 1;');


    PREPARE stmt from @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
...
-- SET @q = CONCAT ('Select `field` from `',table,'` into result limit 1;');
SET @`q` := CONCAT('SELECT `der`.`field`
                    FROM (SELECT `field` FROM `', `table`, '` LIMIT 1) `der`,
                         (SELECT @`result` := NULL) `init`
                         INTO @`result`;');
PREPARE `stmt` from @`q`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
SET `result` := @`result`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
...
```

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and routine parameters [13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae2c0/1)</kbd>

Comment: Hi it shows: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 1' at line 1 0.016 sec

Comment: Thanks you, it seems like work now, however, I am facing another issue as if the field is resulting as no row, then it will result the value from previous non-null result, is there anyway to force it to return null ?